# Remove Source Map section on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, source-maps

Do you know how to remove the source map section on `Visual Studio 2019`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click on the scroll bar, "Scroll bar options".

Select "Use bar mode for vertical scroll bar" instead of "Use map mode for vertical scroll bar".